# Add existing project to blank solution in source control

Tags: visual-studio-2012, tfs

I am trying to put several existing projects in one blank solution. This solution plus existing projects then need to be added to TFS source control.

Is there any way to achieve this? I simply am not able to find out how to get this done. Adding the project to a blank solution is relatively easy. Except it only places references to the existing project, rather than adding the files to the solution.

So when checking-in at sourcecontrol, it does not recognise the projectfiles as they do not get added to the solution, just references.

How can I get this done?

Comment: The location of the projects is probably upwards and outwards of your tfs workspace on your pc. Check where the workspace is rooted on your pc and how it relates to the location of your solution.

Comment: Both the existing projects and new blank solution are located in the same tfs workspace.

Comment: have you tried putting the projects and all files in the same location as the solution? If the projects are not source-controlled yet, then is that an option? and does it help?

Comment: I have tried adding the projectfiles in the same location as the solution. This did not solve the problem. This just changes the referencelocation as the project changed location.

Comment: I managed to do it! Will post an answer in a second.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to figure it out.

1. Add projectfiles of the project to be added to the solutiondirectory.
2. Add a reference to existing project (the one now in your solution directory).
3. In Windows Explorer, rightclick on the projectmap you just added and navigate to "Team Foundation Server" --> "Add".

The showing messagebox will describe which files will be added (they should be ONLY projectfiles, no bindirectory or anything).

Then reopen the solution in Visual Studio and the project should appear to be in source control.

**Edit:** The changes to show up in the pending-changeswindow, you just have to add them manually. They should show as "detected". Select these to be promoted and you should be able to check them in.